Scale a rheostat range
I have a rheostat that ranges between 61/186 ohm, and I'm looking for a method to make it between 16/160 ohm, how can I achieve that using only passive components if possible please.

If it is a fuel sensor, typically the highest resistance will be when the tank is almost empty. Arguably, that is the only point where the accuracy is of much consequence. It might show overfull when full, or (as in this case) never show full even when it is. If that is the situation, you can consider the below "solution", otherwise you can ignore it.

If you shunt the rheostat with 1.1kΩ it will go from 58Ω to 159Ω.

There is not really a simple way to remap the resistance of a rheostat without knowing how the circuit works and other factors.

Nice guess, it’s a fuel gauge, I cannot use a single resistor, it will result to false readings, after further inspection I found that it was a potentiometer (3 terminals) is there a way to make it behave like the rheostat I’m looking for?
